# how to avoid scrolling when we set height of container to 100vh to fit screen height but there is another component on top of it?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code-

```
<div class="header">
  <span>Heading element</span>
</div>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <span>Main content</span>
</div>

.header
{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.mainContainer
{
  height:70vh;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

I want mainContainer to take the full height of the screen. But there is another div on top of it which has his own height of 50px. Now if I give the height of 100vh to mainContainer then the scrollbar appears on the screen which is obvious but how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute` with `top: 0` to header class:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.header
{
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.mainContainer
{
  height:100vh;
  border:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <span>Heading element</span>
</div>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <span>Main content</span>
</div>
```